# Is it possible to travel to China with a UAE stamp in passport?

Tags: china, passport-stamps, uae

I've recently come back from China and on the way back to Europe I made a stopover in Dubai, UAE where my passport was stamped.

If I decided to go to China again, would this stamp be a problem whilst applying for a new visa?

Comment: Is there something specific that makes you think this would cause a problem? Anything in particular you are worried about?

Comment: According to one of the visa agencies in my country it might be a problem. So I rather seek an advice beforehand instead of having my future visa application rejected.

Comment: Why does your visa agency think that would be a problem?  Dubai even has lots of flights to China on Air China, China Eastern, China Southern, Emirates etc.

Comment: I can't think of any passport stamp that would be a problem for China.

Comment: @Peter I am not travelling around the world that much, but definitely good to know that I can go anywhere and not have to be afraid of stamps.

Comment: Why would someone not let you into a country because you've been somewhere else in your lifetime?

Comment: @insidesin, some countries check if there are stamps of a specific country. however China is not one of them

Comment: Countries like Iran, Syria, Saudi Arabia and others wont let you in, if you have an Israeli passport stamp.

Comment: Well yeah, barring any tyrannical country... There's bigger problems to discuss when visiting one of those unstable countries.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. However I asked only about China - UAE. Thanks for joining the discussion though.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - Yes, it is to the question, I was just replying to insidesin's comment.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf Ah, OK. I'd not noticed that. Best to prefix replies with `@username` so it's obvious who they're addressed to and so the person you're talking to gets notification that you said something.

Comment: I'm rather curious what the alleged reason China would object to the UAE stamp might be.

Comment: @R.. I wanted to apply through visa agency, but was told that having UAE stamp could cause troubles. However, people here claim to have not had any problems with this. I even did some research and PRC-UAE diplomatic relationship seems to be very good, so no objectific reason to not to allow someone with both stamaps to enter one of these countries. I suppose that this agency made a mistake, or had some outdated information. In the end, I will rather apply in person, since the embassy is not that far from my home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ever do have a situation where a visa stamp in your passport will preclude you from visiting another country, your passport agency will likely be fine with granting you a second passport.

This happens not infrequently with US journalists--the US government issues them a second passport for what some call the "terrorism tour" countries. (The second passport is not free and is only issued after an interview with an FSO, Foreign Service Officer.)

The idea that you can only get one passport at a time from a particular country is NOT true.

Your mileage may vary if your passport is issued by a country other than the US.

Comment: Haha, I like your expression "terrorism tour", but don't think the United Arab Emirates counts for this ;). You made a good point - if any problems should arise I'd play it safe and ask for 2nd travel document. However, from other comments it seems it will not be necessary.

Comment: Also note that you need to know about the need for a second passport way in advance of travel. -- You need to convince your state dept to authorize the granting of a second passport. Some countries enable their consulates to grant passports, others (eg UK), do not.

Comment: Any *decent* paranoic entry-denying state would of course build up enough intelligence to find out where you've been with your other passport without even looking at any stamps, wouldn't it?

Comment: The good news is that the paranoid entry-denying states aren't decent. So no worries.

Answer (score 18):

I've been to China with a UAE stamp in the same passport.  No problem was raised. I don't particularly see why there would be a problem?

China and the UAE [have pretty good relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China%E2%80%93United_Arab_Emirates_relations).

So in answer to your question - yes, it IS possible to travel to China with a UAE stamp in your passport.

Comment: Great! Can anyone else confirm please? Anyway, I'm very pleased to hear that I won't need to have a new passport issued.

Comment: China and most countries have pretty good relations, everyone loves (and hates) China, and they do the same back. It's modern diplomacy nowadays.

Comment: @Tomas have traveled to both countries too, so here is your confirmation. The only country I would be worried about is visiting Israel and then a Mid East country. Enjoy your travels!

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm Mark Mayo's experience.
It is possible to travel to China with a UAE stamp in your passport.

I base this on my own experience. I have two stamps from the UAE as well as several visas, both business and travel Visas from China in my passport and never experienced any problems at immigration in either of the two countries.